# How does lens design affect the richness of color reproduction?

Tags: lens, color, lens-design

Comparing a kit zoom lens to a faster, 20-year-old prime it seems like the old lens produces richer, warmer color. I've noticed the same kind of comparisons elsewhere. What is the lens actually *doing*? Chromatic aberration, more light, a yellow tint in the glass? How does lens construction affect color?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do lenses affect color fidelity?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/20929/do-lenses-affect-color-fidelity) This question is also interesting and along similar lines - [Were lenses for film designed to focus different colors at different depths, and what does that mean for digital?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/10782/were-lenses-for-film-designed-to-focus-different-colors-at-different-depths-and)

Comment: And also [How does a lens affect the saturation of a picture?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/13258/how-does-a-lens-affect-the-saturation-of-a-picture). I voted you up because it is a good well thought out question, but I do believe it is already covered here in other questions/answers.

Comment: In some cases, old lenses develop a yellow tint because they were made with [radioactive thorium glass](http://camerapedia.wikia.com/wiki/Radioactive_lenses).

Comment: So in other words, most or all of the above. I would probably call it a combination of the higher-quality optics increasing color saturation and contrast, and the older lens having yellowed *just slightly* producing a warmer overall color temperature.